# Append tags to textbox

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I am using the [Tag Manager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3) library.

I have got it working at its most simple level -

```
<head runat="server">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tagmanager.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/tagmanager.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input"/>

    </div>

          <script>
              $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
    </script>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to define a location for where the tags are placed on the page? More specifically I intened on appending the tags to another text box which would act as a container. I can't find anywhere in the documentation of how to specify a location.

Here is a working [example JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2z4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an option available for it if you see the [docs](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3) [scroll to `Tagmanager Configuration`]

> ***tagsContainer***:     Optional jQuery selector for the element to contain the
>   tags. Default: tags appear immediately before the tag input.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tagsManager").tagsManager({
         prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
         CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
         preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
         typeahead: true,
         typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
         typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "New York", "Paris",      "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
         delimeters: [44, 188, 13],
         backspace: [8],
         blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
         blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
         hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA',
         tagsContainer: '#testcontainer'
     });
});

<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager"
/>
<input type="hidden" value="Pisa,Rome" name="hiddenTagList">
<div id="testcontainer"><h2>Tags here:</h2></div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2z4/59/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what kind of output the function you showed would produce, but isn't it possible to just move the produced code with jQuery to wherever you want? like this:

```
<script>
//First execute your function
$(".tm-input").tagsManager();
//Then move it somewhere else
$("#form1").appendTo(".some-other-container");
</script>
```

Where '.some-other-container' is a div with class="some-other-container"

You can also use insertAfter() to move the code after a certain div.